# Yeoman aborts from 'grunt server' because of compass (Windows 8)

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, yeoman

Why won't `grunt server` properly watch/compile scss through compass

ENV:
I am using Windows 8 + Yeoman (generator-angular 0.6.0-rc.1)

I think the same problem on Github:
[Does not seems to work with windows 8, 64bit](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/issues/83)

*For Anyone that doesn't know how to answer my question, is there anything I might add, that you believe, would help lead someone to this answer?  I'm actively watching this thread.*

**Compass is installed and works properly**
[image: I have compass]

**after running Grunt server — the compass:watch command fails and aborts everything**
[image: Compass fails]

If I `grunt server --force` everything works properly expect scss.

**I'm not sure if paths are incorrect so i've linked my Gruntfile.js**

---

```
    // Generated on 2013-11-30 using generator-angular 0.6.0-rc.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    watch: {
      coffee: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:dist']
      },
      coffeeTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:test']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      options: ['last 1 version'],
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },
    coffee: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceRoot: ''
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
          src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false
      },
      dist: {},
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
      dist: {}
    },*/
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }
    },
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
      // By default, your `index.html` <!-- Usemin Block --> will take care of
      // minification. This option is pre-configured if you do not wish to use
      // Usemin blocks.
      // dist: {
      //   files: {
      //     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
      //       '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      //       '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
      //     ]
      //   }
      // }
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
          //collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          useShortDoctype: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true*/
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: [
            'generated/*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'coffee:dist',
        'compass:server',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'coffee',
        'compass',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'coffee',
        'compass:dist',
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin',
        'htmlmin'
      ]
    },
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Finally have solved it.  I have 2 versions of Ruby200 on my computer x64 and 32 bit.  My System Enviroment Variables were set to x64; however, all my gems were installed in 32bit and this is why none of this worked. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Ya this is exactly what I ran into. good to have a reference on here now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue so I uninstalled the 64 bit version of Ruby and installed a 32 bit version. I still got the same error. After further searching I found that after installing compass with "gem install compass" it actually installed a newer released version (sass-3.30.rc.2) then if I installed sass manually with "gem install sass" (sass-3.2.14)

So what fixed this for me was after installing compass using "gem install compass" I uninstalled sass using "gem uninstall sass" and then reinstalled with "gem install sass"

Compass works for me now.